# Portrait vs Landscape Launch Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

An iPad app can support inclusion of launch images in both orientations; presumably, if your app supports auto-rotation, then this would suggest to me that if the user launches an app while the device is in Landscape mode, then the Landscape launch image is used.

But in all the apps I've built and released, this has never been the case. Never once has the Landscape launch image appeared, only the Portrait. After loading, the app will auto-rotate to whatever orientation the device is in, but at launch, it assumes you are in Portrait. Always.

Why?

I have seen many other apps in the store that behave this way, but then there are some seem to always automatically know immediately at first launch, from that first launch image, that you are in Landscape, if that's the case.

How is this done?

Comment: isn't the launch image is determined from the app initial orientation you ?

Comment: I would think so, but no this is not what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it would turn out, the issue was due to leaving out the supported orientations in the plist file for the app. You can add these manually or just select them in the Target page. More details here:

[How to get a landscape launch image to actually appear when launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296515/how-to-get-a-landscape-launch-image-to-actually-appear-when-launched)

Answer (score 1):

iPhone supports only portrait images (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5)

Apps that don't support portrait orientations, provide the same portrait oriented image. For example, Angry birds on iPhone has the same portrait oriented image but the guys painted rotated graphics on it.

Comment: I'm using iPad. It allows two different orientation launch images. But the landscape image never shows no matter what.