# How to get a landscape launch image to actually appear when launched?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have read and put into practice everything [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12), an Apple doc on launch images.

My app supports auto-rotation and according to the document above, if you specify a Landscape launch image for iPad, it will be used when the app launches in landscape mode.

But I have never seen this actually happen in practice. The iPad can be oriented landscape, but the Portrait launch image always shows. This has been my experience on iOS 4 and 5 and on several different apps.

What is necessary to get a Landscape launch image to actually appear?

Comment: Well, first off, what do your images actually look like for both?

Comment: They are indeed different :) One is clearly for Landscape and the other for portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your target settings, look at the iPad deployment info. Ensure that you have selected the supported device orientations that include landscapes. Then under the launch images, have you dragged your images into that field? If not, do that. I've never had a problem.

Comment: Great scott!! I've been assuming that the view controller's handling of rotation was enough; I never bothered to select these. That indeed solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it was a quick fix! Have fun.